# double DataType for images in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, double

a question has been on my mind :

Why should we use double datatype for the image In MATLAB programming language ?

Comment: You can use `uint8`. if I am not mistaken, uint8's are mostly used in graphics and images. Why do you think you should use `double` is up to you.

Comment: This question is equivalent to “why should we put milk in our coffee?”   We don’t need to, but some people do.

Comment: @CrisLuengo - I think there's actually a reason for this one, though! Matlab's implicit narrowing on mixed-type arithmetic means that it's tricky and potentially dangerous to use int types in Matlab code.

Comment: Consider these two expressions: `uint8(200) * 10 / 11` and `200 * 10 / 11` the first expression evaluates to `uint8(uint8(uint8(200)* 10) / 11)` while the second expression evaluates like when you are using a pocket calculator. The first expression produces unexpected result for a user that isn't sufficiently familiar with MATLAB.

Answer (score 3):

For historical reasons, all numeric values in Matlab default to being `double`. Originally, `double` was the *only* numeric type that Matlab supported. Integer types were grafted on later, and in an attempt to preserve back-compatibility, they were defined with unusual behavior: mixed-type arithmetic operations between floating-point and integer types in Matlab implicitly *narrow* to the integer type. (Because in Matlab, numeric literals like `1234` that look like integers actually produce `double`s.) In pretty much every other programming language, mixed-type arithmetic operations implicitly *widen* to the floating-point type.

This implicit narrowing behavior makes it easy to write Matlab code that quietly produces bad results if you have integer values anywhere. So most Matlab programmers, and most Matlab programs, just use `double`s for everything.

Comment: I don't agree with this, plenty of people use integer-valued images, the Image Processing Toolbox supports integers matrices extensively for this purpose. Regarding the narrowing: the floating-point value is not narrowed to the integer type before the operation, the operation is performed with floating-point arithmetic, and the result is cast to the integer type. This is actually what you'd like when you're not dealing with a single value but a (potentially large) array of values: imagine having a huge image as uint8, you don't want it to take up 8 times as much after an arithmetic operation.

Comment: The end result is basically the same: the output of the operation is an integer instead of the floating-point type, which means if integers sneak in to contexts where you weren't expecting them, they contaminate your results.